# How to add textures for a 3d Model using blender

Tags: model, 3d, blender

When i open a 3ds file using blender, it just load a solid block without many texture images file in the same directory. Anyone can help me load full of this model? Thanks in advance :D

Comment: You're unlikely to get an answer here as this is not a programming related question. I'd try some of the other stackexchance sites.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this IS a programming help site, I will say try looking in the UV map editor and check if the textures are there, if perhaps not mapped. Also, if the 3ds file is yours... I'm not sure if this is even an issue with 3DS max but see if the textures are "packed" or included with the .3ds file.